# Google Sheets Macro Loop

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I'm trying to create a way to auto 'click' macro a button on one of my sheets so that it is running autonomously. I have looked at the triggers section to create a time interval trigger every minute with the script but this hasn't worked.

Is there a way to autorun a macro that clicks a button on one of my sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Was calling a script from another sheet.